# Conditionally aggregate dataframe rows that don't contain certain values

Tags: r, dplyr

In df, I'd like to keep only those rows whose `intersect_street` matches a street name contained in `streets` while also adding the `intersection_distance_meters` of the removed rows to the row above it.

**df**

```
> streets
[1] "FRONT ST" "2ND ST"   "3RD ST"   "4TH ST"  

> df
              intersection segment_key intersection_distance_meters intersect_street
1       ARCH ST & FRONT ST         1EW                           81         FRONT ST
2     ARCH ST & MASCHER ST         2EW                           60       MASCHER ST
3         ARCH ST & 2ND ST         3EW                           57           2ND ST
4 ARCH ST & LITTLE BOYS CT         4EW                           28   LITTLE BOYS CT
5       ARCH ST & BREAD ST         5EW                           83         BREAD ST
6         ARCH ST & 3RD ST         6EW                          135           3RD ST
7         ARCH ST & 4TH ST         7EW                          144           4TH ST
```

**Desired output**

```
              intersection segment_key intersection_distance_meters intersect_street
1       ARCH ST & FRONT ST         1EW                          141         FRONT ST
2         ARCH ST & 2ND ST         3EW                          168           2ND ST
3         ARCH ST & 3RD ST         6EW                          135           3RD ST
4         ARCH ST & 4TH ST         7EW                          144           4TH ST
```

I've been using `lead()` from dplyr to add the `intersect_street` and `intersection_distance_meters` for the next row as a new column and then sum them conditionally, but I run into problems when there are multiple non-major intersections in a row (e.g., rows 4 and 5 above).

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(intersection = c("ARCH ST & FRONT ST", "ARCH ST & MASCHER ST", 
"ARCH ST & 2ND ST", "ARCH ST & LITTLE BOYS CT", "ARCH ST & BREAD ST", 
"ARCH ST & 3RD ST", "ARCH ST & 4TH ST"), segment_key = c("1EW", 
"2EW", "3EW", "4EW", "5EW", "6EW", "7EW"), intersection_distance_meters = c(81, 
60, 57, 28, 83, 135, 144), intersect_street = c("FRONT ST", "MASCHER ST", 
"2ND ST", "LITTLE BOYS CT", "BREAD ST", "3RD ST", "4TH ST")), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")

streets <- c("FRONT ST", "2ND ST", "3RD ST", "4TH ST")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I created some extra helper columns---I left them in so the logic is clear.

```
df %>% mutate(
    keep = intersect_street %in% streets,
    grouper = cumsum(keep)
  ) %>%
  group_by(grouper) %>%
  mutate(total_intersection_dist = sum(intersection_distance_meters)) %>%
  slice(1)
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
# # Groups:   grouper [4]
#   intersection       segment_key intersection_distance_met~ intersect_street keep  grouper total_intersection_di~
#   <chr>              <chr>                            <dbl> <chr>            <lgl>   <int>                  <dbl>
# 1 ARCH ST & FRONT ST 1EW                                 81 FRONT ST         TRUE        1                    141
# 2 ARCH ST & 2ND ST   3EW                                 57 2ND ST           TRUE        2                    168
# 3 ARCH ST & 3RD ST   6EW                                135 3RD ST           TRUE        3                    135
# 4 ARCH ST & 4TH ST   7EW                                144 4TH ST           TRUE        4                    144
```